# Integrate of Heaviside Function returns an error answer

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I try to evaluate an Integral of a `Heaviside` function, but it turns out with an erroneous output(zero). Here is my integral:

```
Integrate[HeavisideTheta[k - Sqrt[kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2]], 
          {kx, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
          {ky, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
          {kz, -Infinity, Infinity}, {kx, ky, kz} ∈ Reals]
```

The right answer should be a volume of a sphere, but it seems Mathematica doesn't know it.

Comment: Define `k` first.

Comment: How to define k? Can you make it clear? I add `Assumptions->k>0` in the integral. It returns 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
Integrate[UnitStep[k - Sqrt[kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2]], 
{kx, -Infinity, Infinity}, {ky, -Infinity, Infinity}, {kz, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {k \[Element] Reals}]
(* -(4/3) k^3 \[Pi] (-1 + UnitStep[-k]) *)

Integrate[Boole[k - Sqrt[kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] >= 0],
{kx, -Infinity, Infinity}, {ky, -Infinity, Infinity}, {kz, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {k \[Element] Reals}]
(* Piecewise[{{(4*k^3*Pi)/3, k >= 0}}, 0] *)
```

Comment: `UnitStep` doesn't work. It result 0 as same as Heaviside Step. I need to Integrate a lot of HeavisideStep functions, What can I do?

Comment: @luming Why doesn't it work ? I think it's giving the correct result; if you supplement the more stringent assumption `k>0` then you get the volume of the sphere as you expect.

Comment: In version 8, both methods work even if I leave out the `Assumptions`.

Comment: @Jens I try the code on two differnt computers, both run mathematica7 for students on Windows7. And one of the computers running mathematica8 on linux Fedora16. All of them give the answer 0 when using`UnitStep`and`HevisideTheta` function with or without Assumptions.

Comment: I can confirm that. In version 7 only the 1 dimensional case `Integrate[UnitStep[k - Sqrt[kx^2]], {kx, -Infinity, Infinity}]` seems to work.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Yes,and `HeavisideTheta`function works too in one dimensional case.

Comment: @Jens Mathematica8 gives the right answer in your`UnitStep`function, I was wrong in the previous reply. However, when adding `Assumptions->k>0` in the integral, it does give the right answer, but a error message occurs like this:`Integrate[
 UnitStep[k - Sqrt[kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2]], {kx, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, {ky, -Infinity, Infinity}, {kz, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> k > 0]` '\n' `Refine::fas: Warning: One or more assumptions evaluated to False. >>` I don't know what does it mean.